# error al querer guardar un dato en postgre, IndentationError: unexpected indent

Tags: python, postgresql

estoy tratando de guardar datos de un usuario dentro de postgre mediante python, estoy empezando y tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
try:
   conn = conectar()
    query = '''INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre, apellido, usuario, email, sexo, born, password) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'''
    res = conn.execute(query, (nombre, apellido, usuario, email, sexo, born, password))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    return {"error": False, "message": "datos guardados"}
except err:
    return {"error": True, "message": err}
```

la consola me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\enzo_\OneDrive\Escritorio\backend_python\src\app.py", line 5, in <module>
  from controllers.registrar import Registrar_usuarios as registrar
File "C:\Users\enzo_\OneDrive\Escritorio\backend_python\src\controllers\registrar.py", line 38
  query = '''INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre, apellido, usuario, email, sexo, born, password) VALUES 
  (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'''
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: En python **la indentación es parte de la sintaxis**. Si no indentas el código de forma consistente tendrás un error de sintaxis. En tu caso se debe a que no todas las líneas dentro del try tienen la misma indentación (espacios por la izquierda)

Comment: tienes razon, la variable de la conexion estaba un espacio mas atras, lo corregi y me dio otro error `res = conn.execute(query, (nombre, apellido, usuario, email, sexo, born, password))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`